# Unable to display names and perform edit for json data in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I wanted to do some crud operations for my json data. But I am failing:

1. to `display the names`(I am getting 0, 1 and 2 instead of my
   actual names: `Main1, Main2` and `Main3`)
2. on `Edit` option: I am unable to get my dynamic filed options: it
   should display `dynamic fields/values` only and they can be
   edited/updated with new values

and hence if I click on `Update/Save` button it should redirect to my main page(it is working fine)

Note: on Edit screen: these field values should be editable/up-datable, for example if I select Main1(but it's displaying 0 instead of Main1 on my view currently)

```
"testkey01": "testkey01data", 
"testkey02": 40, 
"testkey03vals": [1, 1, 1]
```

and similarly for other names too.

Please let me know how can I do these and thanks in advance. [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/joUGxsRJaeVsLfge3YRM?p=preview) is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, the task could be achieved with the help of a function that you can declare inside your controller:

```
$scope.getKey = function(item) {
    return Object.keys(item)[0];
}
```

And then use it in HTML like this:

```
<td>{{getKey(value)}}</td>
```

I've updated the plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/orupd2RUyVsL9GPi276L?p=preview).

LE: I've also updated the plunker to solve your edit problem. You were not aware that you had to put the key also. In all honesty your json is quite a mess. You'll still have to work some stuff out from that point on. I hope I helped you a bit at least. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help. Yes, it's working fine.